# OpenLDAP works but service doesn't start during boot

Tags: networking, ldap, openldap

Couple of days ago, we've had to change LDAP Server to which our clients connect. We have no access to the server, only to the clients.
So as soon we changed server in ldap.conf after reboot libnss-ldap doesn't start automatically. We can still connect with our users and the service can be started manually without any problems.

in the boot phase there are couple errors in logs that the server is not available. Directly after the booting, service is inactive (dead). Then we can start it without any problems.

Any idea how to solve it?
Why doesn't it start with the system though we can connect anyways?
Maybe to add some kind of sleep to the service, so it starts a bit after?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.